# Сортировка таблицы с помощью колонки из другой таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица `ACCOUNT_SCENARIO`:

[image: ACCOUNT_SCENARIO]

Нужно отсортировать её в такой последовательности:

1. `ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'CE'`
2. `ACCOUNT_ID` = выбираем колонку, по которой хотим сортировать из другой таблицы, но которая содержит те же данные, что и `ACCOUNT_ID`, только в нужном нам порядке:

   ```
   (SELECT PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
   FROM ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY  
   WHERE ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY_ID = 'CE'
   GROUP BY PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
   ORDER BY MIN(EXCEL_ORDER))
   ```

[image: Колонка, по которой хотим сортировать]

3. Сортируем все строки с одинаковым `ACCOUNT_ID` по `ACCOUNT_DATE`.

Возможно ли в целом написать такой запрос? И если да, то как? Я пробовал писать такую сортировку через `ORDER BY(SELECT колонки из другой таблицы)`, но у меня ничего не вышло.

Comment: В какой базе данных работаете?

Comment: делаете join и сортируете в нужном порядке.

Comment: @Klimenkomud SQL Server

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Спасибо, но это не решает проблемы с пунктом 3.

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану  каким должен быть порядок сортировки - order by PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID (отсортированный по MIN(EXCEL_ORDER)), затем ACCOUNT_DATE? что имеется ввиду под все строки с одинаковым ACCOUNT_ID? если запись есть в ACCOUNT_SCENARIO, но ее нет в ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY  - нужно ли ее выводить и как она должна быть отсортирована?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Порядок сортировки такой же, как я указал выше - сначала сортируем по ACCOUNT_TYPE, затем - по ACCOUNT_ID, затем - по ACCOUNT_DATE. При этом, порядок сортировки по ACCOUNT_ID нужно задать с помощью подзапроса(?) в пункте 2. Этот подзапрос возвращает колонку с данными, идентичными колонке ACCOUNT_ID, только порядок сортировки другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос ниже:

```
select asce.* 
from ACCOUNT_SCENARIO asce
join (SELECT PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID, MIN(EXCEL_ORDER) as EXCEL_ORDER
FROM ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY  
WHERE ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY_ID = 'CE'
GROUP BY PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
) x on asce.ACCOUNT_ID=x.PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
order by ACCOUNT_TYPE, x.EXCEL_ORDER, ACCOUNT_DATE
```

Comment: Меджик вау....)

Comment: Кстати, обнаружил небольшую ошибку в запросе - вернулись данные не только с иерархии 'CE', но и 'CF'. Добавил еще одно условие, и всё заработало:
select asce.* 
from ACCOUNT_SCENARIO asce
join (SELECT PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID, MIN(EXCEL_ORDER) as EXCEL_ORDER
FROM ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY  
WHERE ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY_ID = 'CE'
GROUP BY PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
) x on asce.ACCOUNT_ID=x.PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID
where ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'CE'
order by ACCOUNT_TYPE, x.EXCEL_ORDER, ACCOUNT_DATE

Comment: @АнтонЦуркану Такая ситуация возможно только в случае если одному PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID принадлежит несколько ACCOUNT_TYPE в таблице ACCOUNT_SCENARIO. Но т.к. в вопросе ничего не было об этом - в ответе это условие не добавлял.